# How do you upload a file on gitlab via the web interface?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm on gitlab 7.13 and it says 7.9 has the drag and drop feature already. But I can't seem to figure out where it is. Some sites its on the drop down when you add a file, but I dont see anything.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: It's not a well-designed GUI.  In fact, all my colleagues at work are pushing me to use the command-line version, which is much better.  I agree, just haven't had time to do the self-training to learn the command-line version.  If any people involved with Gitlab look at this, I hope they'll seriously change their GUI.  See my question on column-sorts for example.

Comment: The question I referenced about column-sorts is:  https://superuser.com/questions/1638262/gitlab-repository-web-client-how-does-one-sort-by-columns-such-as-last-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select *Upload file* **not** *New file* from the drop down menu of the '+' icon

[image: Click here to see the screenshot which explains it]

Comment: Unfortunately, this menu does not appear until at least one file already exists.  So if its a new repository and you have not chosen to automatically create a README.md or license by default, the only way is to click on "New file" and copy and paste the contents.  Looks like a design bug to me!