# How do you upload a change to an existing file on Gitlab via the web interface?

Tags: git, gitlab

Referring back to the answer of [How do you upload a file on gitlab via the web interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/1083722/how-do-you-upload-a-file-on-gitlab-via-the-web-interface), how do you upload a *new version* of a pre-existing file on Gitlab, via the web interface? When I select **Upload File**, from the **+** drop down menu, I get a message saying that a file with the same name exists:

> [image: A file with this name already exists]

I don't want to upload the changed file as a *new file*, I want to update the one that is *already there*.

On Github, you just hit the **Upload Files** button and if it has the same name then the already existing file is updated and the change is noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out, in part through Bruce's answer.

The file that I was trying to update was an Eagle schematic, which *is* a text file.

You have to click on the file's name, in the main repository view, to open it. Then a **Replace** button appears. That can be used to upload a new version of the same file:

> [image: Delete button]

Somewhat tedious, and slow, if the file is a megabyte in size. For a project with one file, it is OK, but using GitLab's web interface to update a whole slew of files (i.e. a changelist) would be immensely frustrating. Likewise, an *atomic* change is not possible, at least via the WebUI.

Nevertheless, version history *is* retained using this method.

It is a shame that you can't update the files in the same way as you can on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's in GitLab, you should probably commit a change to the file with git.
If you really want to use the web interface - if it's a text file, click on the edit button and edit it. Saving the file will commit a change.
If it's a binary file you will have to commit a change and push it to the repo.